# what does optional function mean here?

Tags: scala

https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Function1.html

it has 'unlift' method, and mentioned optional function. what does it mean "optional function".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An optional function is a function that returns an `Option`.

From the docs:

> This member is added by an implicit conversion from (T1) => R toUnliftOps[T1, B] performed by method UnliftOps in scala.Function1.  This conversion will take place only if R is a subclass of Option[B] (R <: Option[B]).

Comment: oh. it helps if i did click the link for the 'unlift' defintion. thanks.